# Keyboard Shortcut not moving WPF controls in .NET Core 3.0 projects

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0

**NOTE**: The below issue is related ONLY to `WPF - .NET Core 3.0` project and `NOT` for `WPF - .NET Framework` project.

In a `UWP` project on `VS2019` I can move a control left/right/up/down via `keyboard` by selecting it and then using `Shift+ an Arrow Key`. Likewise, I can change the size of the control by selecting it and using `Ctrl + an Arrow Key`.

In my `WPF` project on `VS2019`, the resizing works with `Ctrl + an Arrow Key` but `Shift+ an Arrow Key` does not work for moving the control. How can we achieve that in a `WPF` project on `VS2019`?

**Remark**: The following two links did not help: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1361350/1232087) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31386696/1232087).

Comment: I have test my WPF net core 3.0  project  with the visual studio 2019 16.2.3. It is working well in design view.

If you implement this by code and run it, please show related code and we can try to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @Yohann I'm actually talking about design view, as well. I've the latest version of `visual studio community edition 2019 16.3.6` that just came today. And, it does not work on `WPF - Core 3.0`. I assume you made sure while creating the project you chose the template named `WPF App (.NET Core)` that is the second template in list when you type wpf in the search box. The first template is  `WPF App (.NET Framework)` - where keyboard shortcut works fine.

Comment: I update the latest version of visual studio community edition 2019  to 16.3.6. Then, I tried your steps to reproduce this strange issue.  I selected the template named WPF App (.NET Core). 

But, the Ctrl + an Arrow Key but also Shift+ an Arrow Key works well. The strange issue did't happened.

Besides, you can go to the [Developer Community  Visual Studio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) and report your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For benefit of readers of this post, here is an update:

```
On my system, after upgrading VS2019 to version 16.4, the issue went away and the Keyboard Shortcut is working now.
```